# Link on Main site that shows also on Subsites

Tags: 2007

I have created a site that has several sub sites off it.  eg group 1. group 2. group 3.
When a user from group 3 logs in all he see's is group 3 site and group 2 user only see's group 2's site etc.  But All 3 groups share certain documents, wiki sites etc. Is it possible to share these with all 3 sites but only having to maintain in the 1 site.  eg I upload a document once and all 3 sites have access to it. Instead of having to upload the document 3 times to all 3 sites.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SharePoint are you using?  sharepoint-15 isn't a valid version.

There are a few ways you can handle this.  You can include the shared content at the top level site or a shared site that all three have access to and then use a Content Query Web Part (CQWP) or DataView Web Part (DVWP) to display the content on the sub-sites.

Comment: sorry Sharepoint 2007.  I'll have a look at them webparts.  I've sort of found a way around it. I create a list on the main site and then put a quick launch on the other sites. 

But what I'm really trying to do is narrow it down to show me one subsite so when I want to generate a report on who has viewed the pages. Instead of generating a report on parent site and the sub sites it just does it on the one subsite.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to setup a few security groups with the relevant users in it and give those groups the appropriate rights on the shared resources.

You can then add links to the shared resources on each site's Quick Access bar using the Site Actions / Site Settings menu.

Comment: I need to run reports on the individual sites. I need to be able to pull of reports on individual teams that have viewed a certain peice of information. Hence why I need the list to show on all subsites as well as the parent. I have a site that has several subsites for individual teams all teams share some information but not all. The only way I can to do it is by creating the list for each site and put the info in, I don't really want to do this as there are 7 sites in all and the documents get updated all the time.